# In JavaScript, how do I get the URL of the JavaScript file, not the location URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, query-string

I would like to use a query string parameter so that way I can specify the name of a DOM element.

I have some code that requires the height of the header and I would like that code to work for any theme. Only at times the header uses the `<header>` tag, at times it has a specific identifier, at times it is a specific class... to be able to reuse that code over and over again, I'd like to include it in a way such as:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/js/my-script.js?c=header"></script>
```

What I want to be able to do is get the "?c=header" part from that JavaScript URL to send search a DOM object with `jQuery(".header")`. Do we have a way to know the URL of the JavaScript itself from the JavaScript being executed?

Obviously, I know of `window.location.href` and that's not the URL I'm looking for.

Comment: Try `getElementsByTagName('script');` and then `var qs = scriptSrc.split('?')[1]`

Comment: Wouldn't `getElementsByTagName('script');` return all the script tags, though? Although I guess I can look for the one with `"/my-script.js"`... Ah...

Comment: You can add ID tag on script and then use that ID to fetch specific script URL

Comment: Mayur, I guess I was confused because I was thinking an ID would not work. However, if you place that specific script in a theme, you can also have a specific ID for that script. I was thinking I did not want to change the page content because that could change whenever the theme gets updated. Although either way with jQuery() it's easy enough to do either type of search.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes it will give you all scripts and you will have to loop.

Comment: @Rajesh if the script is executed in the main scope (not nested in an async function), then it will always be the last script of the DOM, no need to loop. Which is actually the same as getting [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) btw.

Comment: @Kaiido Not necessary. You can have more than 1 script tags. What OP has shown is a sample.

Comment: @Rajesh read my comment again. scripts if not async are executed directly, this means that the **last** script element in the DOM is the one being executed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Kaiido in a comment, there is the `document.currentScript` parameter that gives you access to the `<script>` tag which is currently running. Only there is a small trick to it, that parameter is defined on the first pass, not when executing functions within your script.

So what one can do is save that information, or at least what you need from that object, in the global scope or a static in your object.

In my case, I just did the following:

```
// Script to tweak things on many websites
var this_script_url = document.currentScript.src;

jQuery(document).ready(function()
  {
    // at this point: "document.currentScript === null"

    var qs = this_script_url.split("?", 2);
    if(qs && 2 == qs.length)
    {
      ... // handle qs[1] which is the query string (a=1&b=3&...)
    }
  });
```

Please make sure you don't use a global name that's too generic. It should include the name of your script or abbreviation thereof. Otherwise you are likely to clash with another script's global.

Now if you have a prototype object, I would suggest you use a static member instead of a global.

```
var my_class = {};

my_class.script_url = document.currentScript.src;

// and later you can reference it directly as in:
url = my_class.script_url;
```

This way you are more likely to avoid clashing problems (the *only* thing that needs to be changing in case of a clash is the name `my_class`).

At this point, the ES5 or ES6 class keyword does not offer you to create variables.

Comment: Note that IE prior to Edge didn't support this property, but you can easily polyfill it by getting the last `document.querySelectorAll('script')`. https://jsfiddle.net/4zohbu9b/